# How to show two values in a Vuetify table in one row?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

In a Vuetify Table is a column in which a start date and an end date should be displayed. The date comes from the backend. How can I display the data in my desired format in the table, that in one column is both. First the start date then the end date?

Typescript:

```
export function useSport() {
  const tableRows = ref<TableColumn[]>();

  onMounted(async () => {
    const yesterday: string = format(sub(new Date(), { days: 2 }),'yyyy-MM-dd');
    const endDate: string = format(sub(new Date(), { days: 7 }), 'yyyy-MM-dd'); 
    const searchParams: TableSearchParams = {
      startDate: yesterday,
      endDate: endDat,
    }
    const { data } = await fetchTableRow(searchParams);
    if(data) {
      tableRows.value = data.entries;
    }
  });

  const headers: DataTableHeader[] = [
    { text: 'Sport', value: 'sportsName' },
    { text: 'Sports Id', value: 'sportsId' },
    { text: 'Data of members', value: 'yesterday' },
    { text: 'Last delivery', value: 'lastDelivery' },
  ]

  return {
    tabelRows,
    headers,
  };
}
```

Vue.js:

```
<template>
  <div class="monitoringSports ma-7">
    {{ 'Delivered Sports Data' }}
    <VDataTable
      :headers="headers"
      :items="tableRows"
      :items-per-page="20"
      hide-default-footer
      class="elevation-1"
      no-data-text="No data found"
      >
      <template #item.sportsName="{ item }">
        <AvatarChip
          :variant="AvatarChipVariant.SPORT"
          :objectId="item.sportsId"
          :label="item.sportsName"
        />
      </template>
      <template #item.startData="{ item }">
        <SportsDate :text="item.startData"/>
      </template>
    </VDataTable>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import AvatarChip from '@/AvatarChip.vue';
import { AvatarChipHit } from '@AvatarChip';
import { useMonitoringSports } from './MonitoringSports';

export default defineComponent({
  components: { AvatarChip },
  setup() { const { tableRows, headers }
 = useMonitoringSports();
 
 return {
  tableRows,
  headers,
  AvatarChip,
  AvatarChipHit,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

My typing, I created interfaces which will be used in the ts and the vue part:

```
export interface TableSearchParams {
  //Mandatory
  startData: string;
  //Optional
  endData?: string;
}

export interface TableRow {
  sportsId?: string;
  sportsName?: string;
  values?: [
    {
      data?: string;
      amount?: number;
    }
  ];
}

export interface SportsTable {
  entries?: SportsTableRow[];
}

export interface DataTableHeader {
  text: string;
  value: string;
  align?: 'start' | 'center' | 'end';
  sortable?: boolean;
  filterable?: boolean;
  groupable?: boolean;
  divider?: boolean;
  class?: string | string[];
  cellClass?: string | string[];
  width?: string | number;
  filter?: (value: any, search: string, item: any) => boolean;
  sort?: (a: any, b: any) => number;
}
```

sportsName and sportsId are displayed in the vuetify table. The two data are not displayed in the table. Which leads me to my question. Where do I have a thinking error?

Comment: ***1)*** The export and import names in `MonitoringSports.ts` don't match. ***2)*** You're trying to use `<SportsDate />` without importing it. ***3)*** Overall, the biggest problem seems to be not using an IDE or, if you are using one, consider setting it up properly and paying attention to the highlighted errors and warnings. If you need more help consider [importing](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/getting-started/your-first-sandbox#import-local-projects-via-cli) your local project into codesandbox.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is not the imported <SportsDate> I just did not mention the import here in the code, I did not want to reveal all the paths of my computer.
I do use a IDE, my problem is how can I display:  First the start date then the end date.